# Solve $n(n+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{1004}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Solve:

> $$n(n+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{1004}$$

For the smallest possible $n > 0$.

It's either $n \equiv 0$ or $n \equiv -1 \pmod{1004}$.

The correct answer is $251$, I'm not sure how though.

Comment: You're assuming that $ab\equiv 0$ mod $N$ implies $a\equiv 0$ or $b\equiv 0$. This is not true unless $N$ is prime. For example $2(3)\equiv 0$ mod $6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

As $1004=4\cdot251$ and $(n,n+1)=1$

$1004|n(n+1)\implies$ either $1004|n$

or $1004|(n+1)$

or $251|n,4|(n+1)$

or $251|(n+1),4|n$